# Flixel or Pygame for a small game?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, python, pygame, flixel

- I have some experience in Bash and Python, Lua.
- I've always wanted to try and make point & click quest games.  Most
  quest games I loved aesthetically and gameplay wise were made with
  Flash.

So now I'm pulled apart between Flixel and Pygame since I naively think Pygame is less powerful in graphical aspect (judging from pygame site screenshots)

In short, what are cons and pros?

Comment: "Which technology to use" questions like this are off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of development technology is something you have to decide based on your goals. If you have never written a game before, then the last thing you need to worry about is any sort of middleware limitations, what you need is experience under your belt. Either way, the technology choice should be made based on the skillset of the development team, the designed feature set and aesthetic requirements of the game, as well as the target platform. Either of these choices will get you started and familiar with the technology no problem. This kind of question is pretty open ended, and can turn into a sort of "religious debate", so you should avoid these sorts of questions.

Comment: yes, you are right. Such questions lead to nowhere. Just wanted to clarify my doubts.

Comment: If you want to have a better idea of what technology choice you should make, then you should take the time to design the game, and develop a list of constraints and features you require, as well as what the aesthetic goal is. Additionally, what is your art pipeline going to look like? If you have artists working with you, they are often resistant to using new tools, while programmers will usually use anything just for the fun of it. If you require Maya just to make your game, Maya isn't a cheap product, and this could be a deciding factor itself.

Comment: I think this could have been said in a comment.